# Can I purchase other app /Google play store products from within Unity App?

Tags: c#, android, ios, in-app-purchase, unity-game-engine

(and detect if product has already been purchased)

My problem is this, one of the requirements outlined for the app i'm currently working on is that **players will be able to purchase books inApp.**(*meaning ibooks on ios , and then books from the google play book section on android*). **Once one book is purchased it will unlock all games within the app** (*these are separate mini games, can be purchased separably or in bundles as in app purchase's inApp*).

So i need to be able to launch the purchase from inside the app. Then detect if the purchase went through.This wouldn't be an issue if i was just buying inApp content, but i need the player to buy an outside media and then see if they did or not so that i could trigger the games to be unlocked/ purchased inApp.

Ive thought about triggering it the other way around too but i also hit an issue. so if i treat the "purchase book" as an inApp purchase that actually buys the game bundle and unlocks the games, but then also gives the user the book. how do i give them the book without them having to pay for it again (*as in they now own it on the app store/Google play and could download it without paying again*).

Any thoughts or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you need is to create a non-consumable item for each book.Then the user will unlock that item forever (after purchase). I recommend you to read the unity IAP documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, the issue is that im not trying to detect if an in game item is purchased, thats fine, im trying to detect if another google play/ app store product as been purchased. For example imagine you bought an app, now you buy another app from the same company, if i can detect that you have bought another one of my company's apps, i unlock extra content for you in the first app.

Comment: For Android, Unity IAP returns a list of purchased products after initialization.
For iOS there is a RestoreTransactions method. But because Apple requires entering the user password after calling it every time, I wouldn't call it on app launch. The password field would immediately pop up every time. However, this is only for an specific app... Let me test one thing and I'll be back to you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these things but I'm sure you'd have to authenticate with the google account and request certain permissions for purchases (if they are accessible by 3rd party apps at all)